# GeoTools compilation error

Tags: geotools, maven

I am build geoserver on Windows 7 first time and follow https://www.seegrid.csiro.au/wiki/Infosrvices/GeoserverDevelopmentSetup.

Installed Git, Java, Maven 3, Eclipse and set the path as follows in environment:
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin
and set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

I successfully clone the following in my system.

```
git clone -o geotools https://github.com/geotools/geotools  
git clone -o geowebcache https://github.com/GeoWebCache/geowebcache  
git clone -o geoserver https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver
```

Changed to Geotool directory and run following command.

```
"mvn -B -nsu -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dtest.maxHeapSize=256m -Dtest.maxPermSize=128m -DdownloadSources=true -Dall clean install eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse"
```

### It gives me error:

Results :

```
Tests in error:
  ShapefileReadWriteTest.testReadWritePointTest:74->test:162->test:182-test:203 ╗ FileNotFound

Tests run: 204, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 1

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] Reactor Summary:  
[INFO]  
[INFO] GeoTools ........................................... SUCCESS [  3.973 s]  
[INFO] Build tools for Geotools 2 ......................... SUCCESS [  0.287 s]  
[INFO] Maven plugins for Geotools 2 ....................... SUCCESS [  0.115 s]  
[INFO] JAR files collector ................................ SUCCESS [16:24 min]  
[INFO] Cross-modules javadoc .............................. SUCCESS [04:31 min]  
[INFO] JJTree and JavaCC compilers plugin ................. SUCCESS [06:40 min]  
[INFO] Geotools modules ................................... SUCCESS [  0.062 s]  
[INFO] Geotools libraries ................................. SUCCESS [  0.250 s]  
[INFO] Sample data module ................................. SUCCESS [  7.432 s]  
[INFO] Open GIS Interfaces ................................ SUCCESS [ 25.288 s]  
[INFO] Metadata ........................................... SUCCESS [ 30.944 s]  
[INFO] Referencing services ............................... SUCCESS [01:48 min]  
[INFO] API interfaces ..................................... SUCCESS [  7.715 s]  
[INFO] Geotools plugins ................................... SUCCESS [  0.078 s]  
[INFO] EPSG Authority Service using HSQL database ......... SUCCESS [08:36 min]  
[INFO] Main module ........................................ SUCCESS [ 55.579 s]  
[INFO] Geotools extensions ................................ SUCCESS [  0.109 s]  
[INFO] Feature Based Graphs and Networks .................. SUCCESS [  6.106 s]  
[INFO] XML Parsing ........................................ SUCCESS [  0.142 s]  
[INFO] XML Parsing ........................................ SUCCESS [ 34.922 s]  
[INFO] XML Code Generation Support ........................ SUCCESS [  3.636 s]  
[INFO] EPSG Authority Service using WKT file .............. SUCCESS [  5.060 s]  
[INFO] OGC CQL to Filter parser ........................... SUCCESS [ 57.631 s]  
[INFO] DataStore Support .................................. SUCCESS [  6.155 s]  
[INFO] Property File DataStore ............................ SUCCESS [  5.995 s]  
[INFO] Shapefile module ................................... FAILURE [ 21.647 s]  
[INFO] Grid Coverage module ............................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] GeoTIFF grid coverage exchange module .............. SKIPPED  
[INFO] ArcGrid datasource module .......................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] GML2 XML Support ................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] GML3 XML Support ................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Filter XML Support ................................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] SLD XML Support .................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] WorldImage datasource module ....................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Render ............................................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] OGC Web Service Models ............................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] Xlink Model ........................................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] Open Web Services Model ............................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] Filter Encoding Specification Model ................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] Web Feature Service Model .......................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] OWS XML Support .................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Filter Encoding Specification XML Support .......... SKIPPED  
[INFO] WFS XML Support .................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] XML Parsing Support ................................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] JDBC DataStore Support ............................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] Web Processing Service Model ....................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Web Coverage Service Model ......................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Catalog Services for the Web Model ................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] ArcSDE plugin ...................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] ArcSDE dummy api ................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] ArcSDE support classes ............................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] ArcSDE DataStore plugin ............................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] Dynamic symbolizer module based on JFreeChart and Eastwood SKIPPED  
[INFO] Extensions to EPSG authority factory ............... SKIPPED  
[INFO] EPSG Authority Service using PostgreSQL database ... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Feature-Pregeneralized ............................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] grass raster datasource module ..................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] GTopo30 datasource module .......................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] JDBC DataStore Plugins ............................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] H2 DataStore ....................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Oracle DataStore ................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] PostGIS DataStore .................................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] Feature transforming feature source wrapper ........ SKIPPED  
[INFO] imagemosaic datasource module ...................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] ImageI/O-Ext based grid coverage readers ........... SKIPPED  
[INFO] imagepyramid datasource module ..................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] imagemosaic-jdbc module ............................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] DB2 DataStore ...................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] MySQL DataStore .................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] SQL Server DataStore ............................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] SpatiaLite DataStore ............................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Teradata DataStore ................................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] JP2K based grid coverage readers ................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] OGR DataStore Module ............................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Core OGR DataStore Module .......................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Bridj OGR DataStore Module ......................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] JNI OGR DataStore Module ........................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Vertical coordinate transformations ................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] Dynamic symbolizers for SVG symbols ................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] Coverage Multidimensional Module ................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] API interfaces ..................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] NetCDF gridcoverage module ......................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] GRIB gridcoverage module ........................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] GeoPackage Module .................................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] Application Schema Support ......................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Application Schema Resolver ........................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] Complex Features Support ........................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Application Schema DataAccess ...................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Sample DataAccess .................................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] Brewer module ...................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Vector grids ....................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Validation Processor and Framework ................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] Web Map Server client .............................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] KML XML Support .................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] WCS XML Support .................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] WPS XML Support .................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] WMS XML Support .................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] CSW XML Support .................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Geotools unsupported ............................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Process ............................................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] Process Feature .................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Process Raster ..................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] YSLD Parser/Encoder ................................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] Swing widgets ...................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] SWT widgets ........................................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] Process Geometry ................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] GeoJSON Support .................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] MBTiles Module ..................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] WFS client module (NG) ............................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] polylabel .......................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] ISO 19107 implementation using JTS ................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] Geometries ......................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Web Processing Service ............................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] Application Schema Support (Unsupported Modules) ... SKIPPED  
[INFO] SOLR module ........................................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] Geobuf DataStore ................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Cartographic CSS parser ............................ SKIPPED  
[INFO] GeoJSON Datastore .................................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] CSVDataStore ....................................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] EPSG Authority Factory for Oracle .................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] Next Generation JDBC DataStores .................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] SAS Matlab grid coverage readers ................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Simple Feature Service store ....................... SKIPPED  
[INFO] Aggregating DataStore .............................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] MongoDB DataStore .................................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] GeoTools Documentation ............................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE  
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] Total time: 42:39 min  
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-20T09:38:16+05:30  
[INFO] Final Memory: 150M/247M  
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------  
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire- 
 plugin:2.15:test (default-test) on project gt-shapefile: There are test failures.
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] Please refer to  
 C:\BUILD_GEOSERVER\geotools\modules\plugin\shapefile\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.  
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]  
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.  
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.  
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:  
[ERROR] [Help 1]  
 http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]  
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :gt-shapefile
```

Can any one help in this how to resolve the same.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to build geotools jars you can do so by skipping tests:

`mvn clean install -Dall -DskipTests`

About doing a full build with tests, it has not worked for a long time.

Patches to fix the build are however more than welcomed. See:
https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md